# AIC in R: Back-transformation of model averaged coefficient estimates

Tags: r, aic, regression-coefficients, back-transformation

I am running an analysis using a mixed model with lmer in R. I am using AIC as my model selection process. I have a global model and am including within the selection process all subset models including the null.

My global model:

```
lmer ( N ~ Time * Treatment + (1|Replicate)
```

where time is continuous, treatment a 2-level factor, and replicate is a random effect to account for repeated measures taken over time within the same indivdual. N is Nitrogen and is my response.

Firstly, for my global model I have standardised to a mean of zero and SD of 2, as I understand this is neccessary to allow comparability of variables across models. My top model set (delta AICc >7) has identified 2 models (the interaction model and the addtive model with the two fixed effects).

Thus I have model-averaged across these two models. I have the following output:

```
Model-averaged coefficients: 
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  12.48242    0.13051  95.645  < 2e-16 ***
c.air.ice                    -1.07202    0.26102   4.107 4.01e-05 ***
z.time                        0.50782    0.06954   7.302  < 2e-16 ***
c.air.ice:z.time             -0.38008    0.13722   2.770  0.00561 **
```

My question is how can I obtain parameter estimates that are "normal" - the output estimates are obviously useful for relative comparison of effect size between my variables, but importantly, I would like "true" slope values that I can report in conjunction with the accompanying Figure. For instance, in my model Time runs from 0 to 120 hours, and thus knowing a true slope value I can estimate from my model N at 120hrs using slope parameter*120. But if I used the standardised slope estimate above (z.time 0.50782) this would be N@120hrs = 0.50782*120 = 60.94 which is way, way off the y-axis scale!!

For comparison, the slope of Time for the interaction model is  0.008156, and the slope of Time for the additive model is 0.0059351. So I expect a true Time slope value in the region of 0.007.

I have read that I need to back-transform these estimates, using an inverse-logit transformation of the form

p = 1/(1+1/e^x)

where e^x is exponential and x the parameter of interest. This gives the same value as using the invlogit function in the "arm" package in R. In this instance for my standardised slope:

```
invlogit(0.50782)
```

=0.6242953 which is still off the y-axis!

So clearly the inverse-logit transformation is doing something different and not giving the value I would be expecting.

How can I get true parameter estimates?

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176766/aic-in-r-how-to-back-transform-model-averaged-coefficients) is a (closely) related question. Duplicate?

Comment: I have no experience with these models, but are you sure `invlogit` is not giving you what you need? You have to consider the effects of all the variables to see whether you get sensible results. For example, if you only consider the effect of `z.time` but fail to include the other effects, you might perhaps get a result that seems way off. But does it still seem way off if you include the effects of the other variables and the intercept, too?